# BIND DNS settings on Mac OS X Lion: Errors in .zone file

Tags: macos, dns, bind

I'm using Mac OS X Lion's BIND to set up a local domain "`webapp.local`". I've already set up a VirtualHost in Apache and added "webapp.local" to the host file, which works.

But wanted others on my network to access it.

So I got as far as creating the file `/var/named/webapp.zone`

```
webapp.local.         IN      SOA     webapp.local. root.webapp.local.    (
        20100601
        15
        3600
        3000000
        86400 )
        IN      NS      webapp.local.
        IN      A       127.0.0.1
*.webapp.local.       IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

but running `# named-checkconf /var/named/webapp.zone` in Terminal brings up some errors

```
/var/named/webapp.zone:1: unknown option 'webapp.local.'
/var/named/webapp.zone:10: unexpected token near end of file
```

Using nano keeps adding a new line to the end of the file, which might explain the second error message, though I'm not certain.

Also, adding any comments with `;` would return the error message `unknown option 'comment'`

Comment: ps. I realise that this question might be more suitable on ServerFault rather than SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to check that with named-checkzone, which checks zone files.  Named-checkconf is expecting named.conf (by default), which has different syntax.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkconf

http://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkzone

Answer (score 0):

I like your joke with 127.0.0.1 for **remote clients**

Did you try to use search for format of Bind zone-files?

- [Zone creator online](http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/bind-zone-file-creator.php) for you
- [Sample one](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/mydomain.html)
- [Sample two](http://corpocrat.com/2008/09/29/sample-dns-zone-file-for-bind/)

> ; BIND db file for webapp.local
>
> $ORIGIN webapp.local.
>
> $TTL 86400

```
@       IN      SOA     webapp.local.      root.webapp.local. (
                        2012032301  ; serial number YYMMDDNN
                        28800           ; Refresh
                        7200            ; Retry
                        864000          ; Expire
                        86400           ; Min TTL
            )

            NS      webapp.local.     
webapp.local.   IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Yeah as this is the first time I've ever touch BIND, my configuration provides a good laugh for everyone else. Thanks for the links, I was following some really badly documented guide, I'm closer to correcting the problem.